# Elasticsearch: sort based on rating

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I have a sample data stored similar to below in Elasticsearch 5.5. I can create index, search based on match_all, gte etc. using postman.

```
{
  "name":"Apple",
  "address": {
    "city":"Cupertino",
    "state":"CA",
    "country":"USA"
  },
  "rating":"4.9"
}
```

I need to sort all the entities based on rating, so I am using below

```
{
  "query":{
    "match_all":{}
    },
   "sort" : [
      {
        "rating" : {
          "order" : "desc"
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

But I see below error in postman

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [rating] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to change the rating field to numeric in order to perform the sort on this field.

```
{
  "name":"Apple",
  "address": {
    "city":"Cupertino",
    "state":"CA",
    "country":"USA"
  },
  "rating":4.9
}
```

otherwise, you can enable fielddata on an existing text field using the PUT mapping API as follows:

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
  "properties": {
    "rating": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```